# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')

Tags: next.js13

Gettting the below error when try to do hard refresh several time for nextjs project.
`webpack.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') at l (webpack.js:1:167) at 8532 (631.js:1:10654) at Function.l (webpack.js:1:167)`

the next.config.js looks like this

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require('fs');
const DEFAULT_BUILD_ID = `default-build-id`;

const nextConfig = {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {}
  generateBuildId: async () => DEFAULT_BUILD_ID,
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {

    if (!isServer) {
      config.output.filename = 'static/chunks/[name].js';
      config.output.chunkFilename = 'static/chunks/[name].js';
    }
    return config;
  },
  experimental: {
    isrMemoryCacheSize: 0,
  },
  transpilePackages: ['@acme/ui', 'lodash-es'],
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

updated the outdated dependencies yet the issue still persist. Also this issue only happens when we rename the chunk of the webpacks.